# var self=this multiple times in methods defined on the prototype?

Tags: javascript

If you have to use var self=this for methods on the prototype object. Will you write var self=this inside each method?

Is there any way to avoid writing var self =this inside all methods?

```
function Test () {
}

Test.prototype.method1 = function () {
 var self = this;

};

Test.prototype.method2 = function () {
 var self = this;

};
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what you're talking about?

Comment: You can always use `bind` if you don't want to set `self = this`. But you can't set `self` only once outside, if you are talking about this.

Comment: example of bind would be useful, if you can post some code.

Comment: It *completely* depends on the rest of the code. Some functions let you pass a parameter that sets the `this` value for the callback. The methods like `.forEach()` and `.map()` do this, as does jQuery's `$.ajax`.

Comment: First of all, what do you need `self` for? can you post example of your code where you use it?

Comment: lets say I am using $http angular service. this keyword will be different inside callback function

Answer (score 0):

You only need to create an alias for the `this` context if you are going to be introducing new contexts with function literals that still need to access the *class's* `this` context.

```
function Test () {}

Test.prototype.method1 = function () {
  // This is fine.
  this.someProperty = 123;
  this.doSomething();
};

Test.prototype.method2 = function () {
  var self = this;
  var callback = function() {
    // The `this` here is no longer the same `this` as outside the function.
    self.someProperty = 456;
  };

  var anotherCallback = function() {
    // No reference to the class's `this` needed here.
    alert('Boo');
  };

  this.doAsyncThing(callback);
};
```

Alternatively, you can use `Function.prototype.bind` to force a `this` context:

```
var callback = function() {
  this.someProperty = 456;
}.bind(this);
```

Comment: hmm. I never saw any code with bind method applied on the prototype methods. Theoretically it is possible but I am not sure this is the best approach.

Comment: how to get original this reference again in bind(this) ?